# C - int is a variable so why not use a variable instead of an int?

Tags: c

I was thinking. If this is a variable:

```
int variable;
variable = 12;
```

Couldn't you just do this?:

```
variable = 12;
//Instead of putting int variable before this?
```

I'm new to C and am learning it, just wanted to understand more of it.

Same thing with chars.

Why is my question being voted down? I'm asking questions and you're all helping....

Comment: In some languages you can do exactly that.  C, C++, and C# do not allow that.  They require an explicit definition of the variable's type.

Comment: Every variable needs to have a specified type. Type deduction can be done with `auto`.

Comment: These languages are explicitly, statically typed, which means you need to specify the type of a variable before using it. It's certainly possible to design a language with (mostly) implicit typing (e.g., Haskell) or dynamic typing (e.g., Python) but that's not how these languages were designed.

Comment: Variable **declaration** and variable **definition** are different things, `variable = value;` this is one of the reasons why interpreted languages are slow. You need a basic c book apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Couldn't you just do this?:
>
> variable = 12; //Instead of putting int variable before this?

**No you can't** do this because you must declare it's type first. This

```
int variable;
```

defines a variable that can hold an `int`. If you assign a `string`, "asdsa2", or a `float`, 34.5, you will get a compilation error. Because we can assign only variables of type int to the `variable`.

> So char is defining the variable as a string and int is defining it as
>   an integer.

If you write:

```
char firstLetter;
```

defines a variable of type `char`. That means the variable `firstLetter` can hold a character.

This is `firstLetter='c';` valid. While this `firstLetter="21";` is wrong.

> I see now, but couldn't you do this instead? int variable
>   = 12; or char variable = "string";

Of course you do. This is actually the usual way we assign a value to a variable, think it like below

1. We define the type.
2. We set the name of the variable.
3. We place the equal sign, =.
4. We set the value.
5. We terminate the assignment with a semicolon, ;.

Follow 1 through 5 from left to right.

Comment: So char is defining the variable as a string and int is defining it as an integer. I see now, but couldn't you do this instead?

int variable = 12; 
or
char variable = "string";

Comment: @Figment I am glad that you do.

Comment: @Figment: A variable of type `char` can only hold a _single_ character. In `C` a string is an _array of `char`_ that includes a NUL character as a terminator at the end. So your example `char variable = "string";` isn't valid code.

Comment: I saw it, thanks so much. You cleared it up for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

C is *statically typed*, meaning that every variable has a type that needs to be specified. You specify it by putting the type name in the declaration. You can initialise the variable in its declaration, rather than assigning it later:

```
int variable = 12;
```

but you can't leave out the declaration altogether. Your second snippet is an assignment to a variable that's already been declared, giving an error if it hasn't been. The compiler needs the declaration to tell it the type so that it knows how to assign to it.

You initially tagged the question with C++; that language allows the type to be deduced from the initialiser, to save you writing it redundantly. But you still need a declaration in that case, to indicate that you mean to introduce a new variable, and haven't just mistyped the name of an existing one:

```
auto variable = 12;   // "auto" is deduced as "int" to match 12
```

but C doesn't have this.

Comment: Fortunately _`but C doesn't have this.`_

Answer (score 1):

Well let me tell you. Whenever you want to use a variable in "C", then you will have to define it. Here, "int variable" means that the variable will hold an integer value. Similar is the case for "char" and "float".
This is the rule for defining variables in "C". if you just write "variable=12", then the compiler will not understand which type of value it will hold. Yes, you have to firstly provide the type of the variable so that the compiler understands the variable's data type and compiles accordingly.

Comment: Providing a type is a good idea in C because the compiler ill allocate the right amout of memory to hold it and ill keep a table of fixed memory addresses/ symbols pointing to it's value

Answer (score 0):

In some languages like python, you don't have to declare the data type.  When you write something like

`int variable;`

you are "declaring" it.  When you write

`variable = 1;`

you are "initializing" it.  All variables must be declared first in C because it is a low-level language that is concerned with memory and data types.

Answer (score 0):

In C you have to specify a *type* of your variable.

int variable = 12;

**int** is the type.

**variable** is the name of the variable.

**12** is the value you initialize it to.

What is a type and why do we need it? A type is essentially a way to tell the system how much memory you want to attach to your variable.

Generally on 32 bit machines you have:

int is 4 bytes, char is 1 byte.

If you did not declare the type, you would be wasteful in giving everything 4 bytes, when it may only need 1.

Also types help the programmer determine what a variable must have, such as a char * being a String of characters usually, an int being an integer, a float being a floating decimal point number. There are many uses in having types, and there are languages that abstract types such as python (well, primitive types.)

Answer (score -1):

both in one line:

```
int variable = 12;
```

int is a name of the type and variable is a name of variable of that type